# Disconnect from the database not using the syntax connect reset

Tags: db2

Hi my teacher just taught us the some syntax of DB2 but this certain question he gave us was kind of confusing, knowing that we already seen some instances using disconnect/connect db2.
He now wanted us to disconnect from our db2 database without using the "connect syntax" is that even possible(Well, I think it is since he asked us).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connections in DB2 are established by `db2 connect`, and that creates a Back-end process that is the agent that communicates with DB2. When you perform a `db2 connect reset`, the connection is dropped, but the back-end process (db2bp) still exists. You can also execute `db2 terminate` and that will drop the connection and terminates the back-end process.